I can't import properly this plugin into my Unity project
I'm trying to import this plugin into my unity project (version 2022.3.24f1). I followed the installation guide on the github page as follows:
-I installed Unity Input System from the package manager;
-I changed the Manifest file and now it looks like this:
{
  "scopedRegistries": [
    {
      "name": "Keijiro",
      "url": "https://registry.npmjs.com",
      "scopes": [
        "jp.keijiro"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "com.unity.timeline": "1.4.5",
    "com.unity.modules.uielements": "1.0.0"
  }
}

-I added this scoped register in the package manager:
scoped manager
-I downloaded the zip file of the plugin from Github, extracted it and imported it into the asset folder of the project.
After the process, there are these 5 errors in the console:
errors
Am I missing some steps? I think I did everything as told in the installation guide.

The project from Keijiro is missing access to RtMidi.dll that you can find here:

https://github.com/keijiro/jp.keijiro.rtmidi/tree/master/Packages/jp.keijiro.rtmidi/Runtime/Windows

Inside this scrpit for instance, you have this import: using RtMidiDll = RtMidi.Unmanaged;

https://github.com/keijiro/Minis/blob/master/Packages/jp.keijiro.minis/Runtime/Internal/MidiPort.cs

To solve it you can import manuality from Keijiro repository.

How do I import it manually? I'm trying to use unity's input manager function "add package from GIT url" but it gives me this error "[Package Manager Window] Error adding package: Packages/jp.keijiro.rtmidi/Runtime/Windows.
Unable to add package [Packages/jp.keijiro.rtmidi/Runtime/Windows]:
Package name 'Packages/jp.keijiro.rtmidi/Runtime/Windows' is invalid.
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()"

Download from GitHub and put dll inside Keijiro folder in your project. This folder is inside the Assets folder.
